# Real time microphone in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, audio-recording, microphone

Is there a real-time microphone Delphi component?

I'm looking for one that provides the results without a buffer.

Comment: What do you mean by "without a buffer". The audio data always needs to be buffered a bit. Just read the buffer contents often to get the audio quickly. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to make a live oscilloscope to record the samples from the microphone and then fast plot it(or process it). For example i need to see if i receive an inpulse and then very fast to do something, with out to make a time-out.

Comment: The audio path has already significant delays. Just create a timer with say a 10ms timeout in which you read the buffer and plot the new samples you received. If you want to react to a signal within a few milliseconds the common audio APIs are not what you want, and Windows might not even be the OS you want.

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.oscilloscope-lib.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [AudioLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html) from Mitov Software, which claims to do things you describe. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 9):

You'll want an audio card that has ASIO drivers, such as the higher end Sound Blaster cards. ASIO has very low latency, as it provides a minimal layer between the software and hardware. Then you can use this:

[Delphi ASIO & VST Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/)

Other alternatives include using the FFMPEG Delphi port and, of course, Direct X from Jedi.

Comment: ASIO is what all the music software uses, right?  I believe FruityLoops was originally written in Delphi, and it used ASIO.

Comment: @Warren P, if you're talking about synchronizing with instruments such as keyboards/drum pads, that's MIDI and VST.

Comment: FruityLoops is both a virtual instrument (VST) plugin driven synth and  a MIDI in/out sequencer with realtime effects. So All of the above.

Answer (score 4):

Real time get microphone data in one array :

```
unit WaveSound;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, MMSystem;

const
  NUMSAMPLES = 1024;    // Number of Samples

type
  TIndata      = array[0 .. NUMSAMPLES - 1] of Integer;
  PIndata      = ^TIndata;

  TFrec= record
    Fx, dx  :Integer;
  end;

  function SNDInitWaveIn: Cardinal;
  procedure SNDProcWaveIn(var Indata : TIndata);
  procedure SNDStopWave;

implementation

var
  DevHandle   : Integer;
  WAVEFORMAT1 : TWAVEFORMATEX;
  Wave        : WAVEHDR;

function SNDInitWaveIn: Cardinal;
begin
    with WAVEFORMAT1 do begin
        wFormatTag := WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
        nChannels := 1;
        nSamplesPerSec := 44100;// 11025; //11khz
        wBitsPerSample := 16;
        nBlockAlign := (nChannels * wBitsPerSample) div 8;
        nAvgBytesPerSec := nBlockAlign * nSamplesPerSec;
        cbSize := 0;
    end;
    Result:= waveInOpen(@DevHandle, cardinal(-1),@WAVEFORMAT1, cardinal(0), cardinal(0), cardinal(0));
    If not(DevHandle = 0) Then waveInStart(DevHandle);
end;

procedure SNDProcWaveIn(var Indata : TIndata);
begin
  //lpdata requires the address of an array to fill up data with
      Wave.lpData := @Indata;
  //the buffer length
      Wave.dwBufferLength := NUMSAMPLES;
      Wave.dwFlags := 0;
   //prepare device for input
      waveInPrepareHeader(DevHandle, @Wave, sizeof(Wave));
      waveInAddBuffer(DevHandle, @Wave, sizeof(Wave));
      // if the following statement is removed, the vis. will be a lot faster (avs style)
      // but uses up 100% of cpu!
      // this is why i hate avs
      Sleep(10); // give device a breather
      // the following loop is quite useless, but anyway...
      repeat
          //Just wait for the blocks to be done or the device to close
      until (((Wave.dwFlags and WHDR_DONE)= WHDR_DONE) or (DevHandle = 0));
      If (DevHandle = 0) Then Exit;  //Cut out if the device is closed
      waveInUnprepareHeader(DevHandle, @Wave, sizeof(Wave));
end;

procedure SNDStopWave;
begin
    waveInReset(DevHandle);
    waveInClose(DevHandle);
    DevHandle := 0;
end;
/////////// [sample of use : ] /////////////////
var
  ind :TIndata;    
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SNDInitWaveIn;
  Timer1.Enabled:= true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
    SNDProcWaveIn(ind);
    //code for proc data in "ind" buffer
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    SNDStopWave;
end;
```